# Apollo dust trajectories

Tags: spacetime

[image]

http://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/medium_1x_/public/import/2014/Hsu%20and%20Horanyi%20Graph%20AJP.png?itok=OSqMRad6

This graph shows the observed trajectory of lunar rover dust particles is roughly the same as in a simulated earth case. However, the earth has 6 times more gravity. Is this an accurate graph? Why isn't it 6 times lower in 6 times more gravity?

If we use their parameters (2.7 m/s at 55 deg) the moon trajectory should top out at 3m or more instead of 1.5m.[image]

Comment: Study https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.3699957

Comment: The solid curves give the *explicit* values of $g$ used in the simulations, corresponding to the 1/6th g on the Moon. Are you having difficulties reading the graphs? If so, in what way?

Comment: The solid curves represent gravity on the moon. Notice the values for $g$ in the lower-right corner of the plot. Earth gravity would be 9.8m/s$^2.$

Comment: That means the graph is incompatible with physics since it should be 6 times lower in 6 times more gravity

Answer (score 0):

Equation 8 referenced in the caption is a trajectory modification that incorporates a drag force:

$$z = \left(\frac{V_{Z_0}+V_t}{V_{X_0}}\right)x + V_t \tau \ln\left(1 - \frac {x} {\tau V_{X_0}} \right) \tag{8}$$

$g$ doesn't appear in it at all.  My interpretation is that the green lines show only the simulation of earth atmosphere drag, not the modification of $g$ as it is on earth.

> If we use their parameters (3 m/s at 45-55 deg) the moon trajectory should top out at 3m or more instead of 1.5m.

The graph is referencing clip#1 only.  Their figures are $V_{Z_0} = 2.23 m/s$.  When I use that and a value of $g_M = 1.6m/s^2$, I get a $z_{max}  \sim  1.5m$

$$t = \frac{V_{Z_0}}{a} = \frac{2.23 \text{m/s}}{1.6 \text{m/s}^2} = 1.4\text{s}$$
$$z = V_{Z_0} t + \frac12 at^2 = 3.12\text{m} - 1.57\text{m} = 1.55 \text{m}$$

Comment: You claimed vz0 and v0 are the same.